# .navbar-collapse .collapse .in is not removed when window is resized

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap 3 the class "in" is not removed from the collapsed menu markup when the screen is enlarged.

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tZXTv/)

[Also see the github issue here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13245), **Is there a non jquery fix for this?**

the jsfidle code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="bgbanner">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="logo" href="#"></a>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
          </div>
          <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a id="nome-logo" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Institucional</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Horários</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Cronograma</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Cardápio</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Fotos</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Vídeos</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Localização</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Contato</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li><a href="#">Arquivos</a></li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Siga-nos <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Tumblr</a></li>
                  <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">RSS</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

            </ul>

          </nav><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you just looking for a CSS only solution then?

Comment: That would be gret yes, or javascript one that doesn't require me to add event resize listeners. The github page doesn't offer any solution and jquery is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Jquery following code should be your solution:

```
$(window).on('resize', function () { if (window.innerWidth > 768) $('.navbar-collapse').removeClass('in') })
```